# My flutter app is getting stuck at "Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk..." and then nothing happens

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

As i mentioned in the question,i cannot see anything in the console but **Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...** and i just cannot understand the reason because my app is working in the device. I can change the pages but the little informations that i want to see, the prints that i entered in the code are not visible and its very annoying.

Before asking here i have been looking the other questions about this problem but the answers in that questions did not worked for me so i end up asking this in here, i hope you can help me.

here is the console after i click the run button;

```
Launching lib\main.dart on LG H850 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
```

an here is the **flutter doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778], locale tr-TR)
   • Flutter version 1.17.0 at C:\Users\Mahir Yakup Şahin\flutter
   • Framework revision e6b34c2b5c (8 days ago), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
   • Engine revision 540786dd51
   • Dart version 2.8.1


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
   • Android SDK at C:\src\Android
   • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
   • ANDROID_HOME = C:\src\Android
   • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
   • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
   • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
   • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
   • Dart plugin version 192.7761
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
   • VS Code at C:\Users\Mahir Yakup Şahin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
   • Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
   • LG H850 • LGH850b31f3def • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

• No issues found!
```

I will be very grateful for any kind of help.

And also i tried in the vscode as well, here is the  result,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvIQt.png)

and sometimes i get an error like this;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngqTL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try "flutter clean", that helps in lot many cases..seems like yours is also one of those..

Also..make sure that you have enough storage space on your device (phone or emulator, whatever you re using)..the description on the second image seems like because of the storage issue.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer but i've tried flutter clean for several times but unfortunately it did not worked for me and for the storage, i do have enough storage in the device.

Comment: @MahirYakupŞahin did you find a solution for this? I'm stuck

Comment: @arisalexis i actually don't remember but currenlty i am using the emulator from android studio so most probably i couldn't find any solution.